# Process of finding device hostnames on LAN

Tags: protocols, fingerprinting, lan

Is there a reliable way to retrieve hostnames from LAN devices without having to install extra software or performing nmap-style OS fingerprinting?

I'm ideally looking for either a protocol that has something like this built in or a program that comes installed as default.

Comment: What about DHCP logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful to know what operating system you're using, also some idea of the network topology.

Some devices announce themselves using mDNS or perhaps the network supports reverse DNS lookup with clients providing their hostnames during DHCP exchanges.

If DNS is available on the network, nslookup is available on most platforms `nslookup xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Then there is NetBIOS, on Windows you could try `nbtstat -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Also ARP might be useful `arp -a`